# Select Distinct Set Common to Subset From Join Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a join table for m-2-m relationship between `booth` and `user`

```
+-----------+------------------+
| booth_id  |          user_id |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 |                1 |
|         1 |                2 |
|         1 |                5 |
|         1 |                9 |
|         2 |                1 |
|         2 |                2 |
|         2 |                5 |
|         2 |               10 |
|         3 |                1 |
|         3 |                2 |
|         3 |                3 |
|         3 |                4 |
|         3 |                6 |
|         3 |               11 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

**How can I get a distinct set of `booth` records that are common between a subset of user ids?** For example, if I am given `user_id` values of `1,2,3`, I expect the result set to include only `booth` with id `3` since it is the only common `booth` in the join table above between all `user_id`'s provided.

I'm hoping I'm missing a keyword in MySQL to accompish this. The furthest I've come so far is using `... user_id = all (1,2,3)` but this is always returning an empty result set *(I believe I understand why it is though)*.

Comment: not sure, does mysql have an `in` statement? `user_id in (1, 2, 3)` or you could just `(user_id = 1 or user_id = 2 or user_id = 3)`

Comment: Yes, MySQL has `IN`, but that will give me a union of all `booth_ids` associated with *any* of the `user_ids`. I need only the `booth_ids` common between **all** `user_ids`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query for this will be:

```
select booth_id from table1 where [user_id]
in (1,2,3) group by booth_id having count(booth_id) = 
(select count(distinct([user_id])) from table1 where [user_id] in (1,2,3))
```

If this could help you creating the MySQL query.